# Make an API call from a cloud page that requires NTLM authentication

Tags: api, soap-api, authentication

I'm aware of the process needed to make an API call from Marketing Cloud Cloud pages using Script.Util.HttpRequest

Authentication using this is simple when using OAUTH however I need to connect to a server that requires NTLM auth.

Is there any simple way in which this can be accomplished?

Any resources would be much appreciated.

Comment: Simple or out of the box - no. Some (older) NTLM endpoints can be configured to automatically downgrade to HTTP Basic Auth, that would be "simple".  Else, you can try rolling a basic NTLM client by porting it from another implementation ([Apex](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/5224/call-webservice-with-ntlm-authentication)) or go through an external proxy that will translate to NTLM

Comment: Great thanks for the reply. Yes this confirms what I thought would be the case (not straight forward). Also agree potential to downgrade to HTTP Basic Auth would be preferred route. Thank you for additional resources re. Apex